# C - little code, file descriptor, segmentation fault

Tags: c, linux

I have write this code but i have a problem

first i have a function that create a file descriptor (fd)

```
int fd;//global

static int init_fd(int fd) {
    remove("file descriptor.txt");//if yet present
    fd = open("file descriptor.txt", O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, 0666);
    if (fd == -1) {
        printf("Error in opening the file descriptor!\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    return fd;

}
```

the second function is a handler function

```
static int handler(struct connection *conn, enum event ev) {


...

        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < array_size; i++) {
            if (!strncmp(conn->uri, uri_array[i], strlen(uri_array[i]))) {
                func_array[i](conn->request_method, conn->uri, NULL, init_fd(fd));
                close(fd);
                fd = open("file descriptor.txt", O_RDONLY);
                ret = read(fd, &buf, BUFSIZ);
                if (ret == -1) {
                    printf("Error in reading!\n");
                    exit(0);
                }
        ...
}
```

with fun_array is a pointer to function

```
httpCallback_t func_array[MAXARRAY];
```

and the function is

```
void http_serve1(const char *method, const char *path, const httpOptions_t *options, int fd) {
    const char *string = "All is ok1!";
    int ret_value;

    // send header: 200 OK
    ret_value = sendHeaders(fd, TIMEOUT_SEC, NETHTTP_HTTP_HEADER_200, NETHTTP_Content_Type_text_html_utf8, NETHTTP_CRLF, NULL);

    // close the file descriptor
    close(fd);
}
```

and the function sendHeaders is

```
size_t sendHeaders(int fd, int seconds, const char* header1, ...) {
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, header1);
    size_t totalSize = 0;
    const char* hdr = header1;
    while (hdr != NULL) {
        size_t result = sendHeaders(fd, seconds, hdr, NULL); // segmentation fault
        if (result < 0) {
            return result;
        }
        totalSize += result;
        hdr = va_arg(args, const char*);
        va_end(args);
        return totalSize;
    }
    if (size == SIZE) {
        setErrorCode(ERROR);
        return ERROR;
    }
    size_t sizewrite = 1024;
    tmp[size] = strdup(hdr);
    write(fd, tmp, sizewrite);
    setErrorCode(SUCCESS);
    return SUCCESS;

}
```

my problem is that my code create a file descriptor, but it doesn't write inside, and during the run i have problem with segmentation fault. anyone have a suggest?

Comment: Not sure if related: `if (result < 0)` makes no sense. `size_t` cannot be negative.

Comment: Start by building a version of your program with debug information (add the `-g` flag to gcc). Then run your program in a debugger, it will stop at the location of the crash and let you examine and walk up the function call stack. If not already in your code, then walk up the stack until you are in one of your functions, there you can examine the values of variables. If you still can't figure it out, then at least edit your question to show *where* the crash happens.

Comment: This recursion will never end `sendHeaders(fd, seconds, hdr, NULL);` due to header is != NULL.

Comment: Here is next issue, I think. Dont know what type `tmp` represents `tmp[size] = strdup(hdr);` but after this action you use it as array of chars so you're trying assign char* to char;

Comment: thanks for reply! But why hdr!=NULL is the problem? While should run until i find NULL (that is the 4 param)? is it correct?

Comment: char *tmp[SIZE]; it is declared global

Comment: `const char* hdr = header1;` and after you check `hdr != NULL` you do call `sendHeaders(..,hdr)` again ..and again ...and.. BUM

Comment: your last reply, it isn't more clear for me! Can you repeat? Thanks

Comment: how can fix it? Regards

Comment: Loop instead of recursion?

Comment: It's not a matter of misunderstanding. I see in your code a lot of basic issues. You should probably read about C a bit more and resolve your problem by yourself.